# Question about expection of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Assume that $X\sim exp(0.001)$.
We are talking about cars and $X$ is the lifetime of a car (at days).

We buy **two** cars, what is $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$?

Can I use the fact that: $E(X)=\frac1\lambda$ and $Var(X)=\frac1{\lambda^2}$?
So: $E(X)=\frac{1}{0.001}\Rightarrow$  $E(2X)=2E(X)=2000$?
And same thing for $Var(X)$ - $Var(2X)=4Var(X)=\frac{4}{0.001^2}$.

I'm right? Or I miss something...
Thank you!

Comment: What is $X$ in the case of two cars? Presumably, the lifetime of an individual car is the same no matter how many cars you have. Do you mean what is the expectation and variance of the length of time you have a working car?

Comment: @snarski - Yes! but I need to calculate the expectation and variance of the lifetime when I have to cars.

Comment: I assume you meant "the lifetime when I have **two** cars"?

Comment: @snarski - until one of them will be broken. You understand it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ denote the lifetimes of two cars. We assume that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. exponential: they are independent because one car breaking down does not affect the other car, and they are both exponential with parameter $\lambda = 0.001$, hence identically distributed.

The length of time you have two cars is the length of time until the first car breaks down, i.e. $Y = \min\{X_1, X_2\}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
P(Y > y) &= P(X_1 > y, X_2 > y) \\ &= P(X_1 > y)P(X_2 > y) \\
&= P(X_1 > y)^2\\
&= (e^{-\lambda y})^2,
\end{align*}
from which we see that $Y \sim \exp(2\lambda)$ (since $P(Y \leq y) = 1 - e^{-2\lambda y}$, which is the cdf of $\exp(2\lambda)$). Therefore, $E Y = \frac{1}{0.002}$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{0.002^2}.$

Note that this is a *different* question from asking what $E(X_1 + X_2)$ is (i.e. the total amount of time you have any car).